# how can we explain that $\int_{0}^{L}1 + \frac{1}{2}(u'(x))^2dx - L = \int_{0}^{L}\frac{1}{2}(u'(x))^2dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Probably a very silly question. However, I don't know what mathematical notion to invoke to solve it.

I have a problem where, using a linear approximation we can say:

$$\sqrt{1 + (u'(x))^2} \approx 1 + \frac{1}{2}(u'(x))^2$$

With this, the change of length $\Delta L$ of the string is given by:

$$\Delta L = \int_{0}^{L}\sqrt{1 + (u'(x))^2}dx - L = \int_{0}^{L}\frac{1}{2}(u'(x))^2dx$$

I  guess that what is implied is that $-L$ becomes $-1$ when inserted into the integral as follow

$$\Delta L = \int_{0}^{L}\sqrt{1 + (u'(x))^2}dx - L = \int_{0}^{L}1 + \frac{1}{2}(u'(x))^2dx - L = \int_{0}^{L}\frac{1}{2}(u'(x))^2dx$$

however how can we explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that $\int_{0}^{L}\sqrt{1+u'(x)^2}\,dx-L$ **is not** equal to $\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{L}u'(x)^2\,dx$ (as can be easily checked by considering $u'(x)=x$ and $L=1$), but since the Maclaurin series of $\sqrt{1+z}$ is $1+\frac{z}{2}+O(z^2)$, if $|u'(x)|\ll 1$ (i.e. if $u(x)$ is approximately constant on $[0,L]$) we are allowed to state

$$ \int_{0}^{L}\sqrt{1+u'(x)^2}\,dx-L \approx \int_{0}^{L}\left(1+\frac{u'(x)^2}{2}\right)\,dx - L = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{L}u'(x)^2\,dx $$
where $\approx$ actually holds as a $\leq $.

Comment: many thanks @Jack D'Aurizio. However my question was actually one level below: how can we state that "$−L$" (**outside** the integral)  becomes "$−1$" when inserted **inside** the integral

Comment: $\int_{0}^{L}1\,dx = L$

Comment: thanks, it was easy indeed but just needed that!